# Hidden playlists on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

If you visit https://www.youtube.com/@Oxfordonlineenglish1/videos, there will be a video *Talking About Online Shopping* from the *IELTS Exam Lessons* playlist. And of course, you can click on the playlist label above its title and then you can watch all the videos from that playlist.

But if you visit the link above and then simply click "Playlists", the *IELTS Exam Lessons* playlist won't be listed there.

Does it mean you can have hidden playlists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at a **selection** of "Created Playlists" not the complete list. They are likely ordered by most recent.  In this way it leaves room on the same page to display a selection of the "Most Popular" playlists as well.

Selecting the down arrow (*image: show more*) will uncover more playlists, and following that there is also a "Show All" link to uncover any remaining (*image: show all*).

<kbd>Show More</kbd>
<kbd>[image: down arrow]</kbd>

<kbd>Show All</kbd>
<kbd>[image: Show All]</kbd>

<kbd>Desktop Version</kbd>
<kbd>[image: Desktop Version]</kbd>